Why do my cookies delete when I refresh my page?
I am building a full stack MERN application and am using cookies. My login route looks something like this:
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Trying to login...")
   

 ....
        const expirationDate = new Date();
        expirationDate.setTime(expirationDate.getTime() + (3 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 

        res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true, expires: expirationDate});
     res.send({ success: true});

Oddly enough, the problem I am facing is refreshing the page. When I test locally (localhost 3000 & 8000), refreshing the page does not remove the cookie. When I deploy my site and test the refresh, the cookie disappears.
I believe this may have something to do with the domain of my deployed site and backend being different but I am not sure.
I tried putting the following code in my server file, which allowed the cookie to persist past refreshes on my local testing:
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});````


The Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is very likely unrelated. When you deploy your app, do frontend and backend really come from different superdomains (for example, .fronend.com vs. .backend.com)? Only then would third-party cookies be involved.

Yea, my front end is deployed on firebase and my backend on render.com. I do get the warning in chrome about third party cookies too. I'm just having trouble getting past the third party cookies

But cookie is then blocked already with the first request, not just after page reload, right?

No the cookie is not blocked at all which is what is confusing me. After my login route, the cookie is created. It's only after page reload that it gets deleted.

Can you give a minimal reproducible example?
